# How can I pass a List<T> to another List of type that T implements

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have a basic class that inherits an interface as below

```
public interface IRefDataItem
{
    int RefID { get; set; }
string Code { get; set; }
}

public class RACodeItem : IRefDataItem
{
    public int RefID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a method that return a List of RACodeItem which I am attempting to assign to a List of IRefDataItem as below

```
List<IRefDataItem> codes = GetRACodes( ); //GetRACodes returns List of RACodeItem
```

I'm getting an error here stating that cannot implicitly cast type List  of RACodeItem to List of IRefDataItem, despite the fact that RACodeItem inherits IRefDataItem

Am I missing something simple here? How can I cast a List of T to a List of an interface type that T implements?

Cheers

Stewart

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: what is the signature of the function "GetRACodes( );"

Comment: 3.5. Signature is irrelevant, only thing that is important is the type of list its returning. Answer below basically answers the question for me and explains why it wasn't working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand why you are trying this but if you think about you will realise this can't work.

For example (This code won't compile)

```
public interface ITest
{
}

public class Test1 : ITest
{
}

public class Test2 : ITest
{ }


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<ITest> list = new List<Test1>();

    list.Add(new Test1());
    list.Add(new Test2());

}
```

The problem is you can't add Test2 to a List of Test1. Declaring you list as `List<ITest> list = new List<ITest>();` will compile and you can add both Test1 and Test2.

Comment: Good point, but note that it works for IEnuemrable<T> which is covariant (because it doesnt have an add method)

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have a following hierarchy. Animal -> horse, cat
Now you have List. You can assign both horse to it and cat to it.
But our list should have same type of animal.

Eric Lippert has an excellent blog about this..
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx